# How to combine boost::exception with boost::unit_test and have a nice message

Tags: c++, unit-testing, exception, boost

When I have the following auto test case :

```
class MyException: virtual public boost::exception, 
                   virtual public std::exception 
{ 
};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ExceptionTest)
{
    BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(MyException());
}
```

Running the test gives:

```
ExceptionTest.cpp(14): fatal error in "void ExceptionTest::test_method()":
   std::exception: std::exception
```

How can I change this so the name of the exception (`MyException`) and `boost::diagnostic_information()` is shown instead of `std::exception` ? I tried registering my own exception translator to the execution monitor but it seems `std::exception` is handled before any registered translator is tried.

I am using boost 1.44 and gcc 4.4.5 on Linux.

Comment: I though this is resolved in Boost.Test trunk. It's possible I did not move the changes into the release - did not have much time to work on Boost.test lately.

BTW, did you register translator for your exception or std::exception?

Also, Why do you need virtual inheritance from std::exception?

Comment: @Gennadiy Rozental: I tried registering it for my exception and boost::exception but it did not work. Ofcourse it is possible I made a mistake when registering. (I tried `boost::unit_test::unit_test_monitor.register_exception_translator<MyException>(&handler);` in several places like a global fixture and in the test self.)

Comment: @Gennadiy Rozental: The virtual inheritance from `std::exception` is because without it `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION` will not compile and according to the docs of `boost::exception` it is a 'good thing' to do: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/exception/doc/frequently_asked_questions.html

Comment: @Gennadiy Rozental: I tried registering my own translator again and somehow it works now. I guess I made a mistake earlier. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to do this:

Use a global fixture like so:

```
#include "boost/test/unit_test_monitor.hpp"

class Fixture
{
    public:
        Fixture();
        ~Fixture();
};

void translateBoostException(const boost::exception &e)
{
    BOOST_FAIL(boost::diagnostic_information(e));
}

Fixture::Fixture()
{
    boost::unit_test::unit_test_monitor.register_exception_translator<boost::exception>(&translateBoostException);
}

Fixture::~Fixture()
{
}

BOOST_GLOBAL_FIXTURE( Fixture )
```

Then the following test:

```
class MyException: virtual public boost::exception, 
                   virtual public std::exception 
{ 
};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ExceptionTest)
{
    BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(MyException());
}
```

Gives:

```
Running 1 test case...
/home/..../SetupTestFixture.cpp(18): fatal error in "ConfigFile":
/home/..../Test.cpp(16): Throw in function void ConfigFile::test_method()
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<MyException>
std::exception::what: std::exception


*** 1 failure detected in test suite "ExceptionTest"
```